# I want to create a method and write code for getCurrentSession in that method and use it in all the remaining methods

Tags: hibernate

```
This is my DaoImpl

import com.ram.model.Employee;

@Repository
public class EmployeeDaoImpl implements EmployeeDao{


    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void ses(Session session){
        session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    @Override
    public void addEditEmployee(Employee emp) {

        ses(session);
        session.saveOrUpdate(emp);

    }

}
```

How can I do this?

I think this is wrong declaration of session.

How to declare Session and use it in all the methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this as:

```
@Repository
public class EmployeeDaoImpl implements EmployeeDao{


    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public Session getCurrentSession(){
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    @Override
    public void addEditEmployee(Employee emp) {
        getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(emp);

    }

}
```

Also you need to study basic java concepts like variable scopes, methods in java, take a look at [this](https://www.javatpoint.com/variable-datatype) link it might help.